# Cant change theme PrestaShop 1.7.3.1

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I created theme for PrestaShop 1.7.3.0 and its work fine. Im get started from Classic theme. I change folder name, theme.yml, add some custom hook's, strings, css/js... and its work perfect for me (its mean without error in apache log, or notice in debuger in PrestaShop). 
I download a new version of PrestaShop (1.7.3.1) and i upload my theme in name_theme.zip from backoffice. (1 TRY) - PHP5.6 Upload was succes BUT when i try change theme from Classic to my theme i see notice sth like: u dont have permission to disable this module'. Ok I chceck debuger its any notice/log is empty. Ok next try on php7.0 also the same notice AND on php7.1 that same, of course without anny errors log or somthing. Only fck notice -,- Anynone have idea how to made to work with.

I try with this: https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/pull/8965 but didnt helps for me...

Thx for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to database and search for table **ps_shop**. Then change **theme_name**  to one what u have.
Default is "classic".